# Is there a way to create multiple columns of text with alphabetical ordering going down each column not across the columns

Tags: columns

My developer says that in wordpress, when creating multiple columns of text (which are all hyperlinked), it is NOT possible to do the alphabetical order vertically, ie in alphabetical order as one scans down each column, but rather it can only be ordered across the columnns - please see attached image.

Is there any way for vertical alphabetcial ordering to be achieved ?[image: column examples]

Comment: In what context? In the editor? In a template? In a page builder plugin? Just with CSS?

Comment: Im not sure but I know that its a custom coded site, with wordpress templates and he said it was not possible to do in wordpress and that it will result in things breaking

Comment: Well it's certainly possible with CSS using the `columns` property, but that doesn't have anything to do with WordPress. Whether that will work in your specific case is impossible to say as there's no implementation details here.

Comment: It's very possible, using pure CSS, PHP, or a combination of both.